# Changing the database schema at runtime (ASP.NET, Entity Framework, .NET 6.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Changing the database schema at runtime stopped working after migrating to .NET 6.0 (to .NET 5.0 - everything worked). Please advise how to solve this problem. DBMS - PostgreSQL, ORM - Entity Framework.

For each project in the developed system, there is a separate schema in the database. Sending an HTTP request to the server switches to the correct project schema to interact with the project data. **Runtime switching has now stopped working, the schema is only changed when the very first request is sent after the application starts.**

I'm using the `ModelCacheKeyFactory` interface override approach.

**MultiTenantModelCacheKeyFactory.cs:**

```
public class MultiTenantModelCacheKeyFactory : ModelCacheKeyFactory
{
    private string _schemaName = null!;

    public MultiTenantModelCacheKeyFactory(ModelCacheKeyFactoryDependencies dependencies) : base(dependencies)
    {
    }

    public override object Create(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context is ProjectDatabaseContext dataContext)
        {
            _schemaName = dataContext.SchemaName;
        }

        return new MultiTenantModelCacheKey(_schemaName, context);
    }
}
```

**MultiTenantModelCacheKey .cs:**

```
public class MultiTenantModelCacheKey : ModelCacheKey
{
    private readonly string _schemaName;

    public MultiTenantModelCacheKey(string schemaName, DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _schemaName = schemaName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _schemaName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IModelCacheKeyFactory, MultiTenantModelCacheKeyFactory>());
```

**MyDatabaseContext.cs:**

```
public sealed class MyDatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    ...

    public string SchemaName { get; }

    public MyDatabaseContext(ISchemaProviderService schemaProviderService,
        DbContextOptions<MyDatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        SchemaName = Task.Run(schemaProviderService.GetSchemaName).Result;
        Task.Run(CreateSchemaIfNotExists).Wait();
    }

    ...
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.HasDefaultSchema(SchemaName);
    }

    private async Task CreateSchemaIfNotExists()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 5 has different architecture from .NET 6.

First of all .Net 5 you can implement the middleware in startup.cs.
This one is different in .NET 6 because now we have program.cs for this job.

I had already implemented the db schema in .net6 and i didn't found something
difficult.

You can read this helpful [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).